# Sorting MySQL Search Results AFTER Return

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, search

I have a products page showing all the products for sale on my site, with links on the side to allow the user to narrow down the results, for example by color.  So if they click on the "Red" link, only products that are red are shown. The database tables are setup so that each color has a value of either "yes" or "no", so when the links are clicked, the query looks like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['color'])) {
  $color = filter($_GET['color']);
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE $color='yes'") or die (mysql_error());
}
```

Then later, I have a while loop to display the products:

```
<?php 
   while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
     ...Display product info here...
   } 
?>
```

The part I'm having trouble with is sorting the results AFTER they are returned.  There are additional links on the page to sort the returned results by "Price" and by "Newest".  I'm having trouble with the logic of how to use those sort links.

For example, after I click on the "Red" link, I can see only the red products. Now I want to be able to click on the "Price" link which should sort by price only the red products.  I don't know if I can sort the results after they have been returned or do I re-query the database with the additional condition ( ORDER BY price ). If the second case is the right approach, how do I append the condition to the previous query and requery the DB? Can anyone help me out with this? I've been working on this for a couple of hours with no luck!

Comment: Queries are just strings, so modifying a query shouldn't be so hard. You will want to use prepared statements btw., or otherwise use proper SQL escaping; what you have now is dangerous code.

Comment: As seen above, I have a custom "filter" function to filter out harmful input in the query strings.

Comment: Hmm, okay, I see that the request values are used for column names so prepared statements wouldn't actually work in this case. .. that said, you should probably still use it anyway =D

Comment: I'm not an SQL expert by any stretch of the imagination. Can you explain how my code is dangerous?

Comment: Depends what the filter function does (if might be filtering the possible values or using mysql_real_escape_string), but potentially your script is open to SQL injection. If someone entered something like "1;SELECT * FROM PasswordsTable #" in the color field they might get some data that you would rather keep hidden.

Answer (score 0):

javascript

you need something like

http://tablesorter.com

PHP ,

pass the value and asc/desc to server side , query like

"SELECT * FROM products WHERE $color='yes' order by price"

pls use mysqli

Comment: Thanks, but this would work. The customer has a very specific design drawn out, and this doesn't fit.  I just have two links above the search results for sorting by Price and Newest.

Answer (score 0):

Just redo the query with an ORDER BY clause added. Certainly on a simple query like this.

However it is possible to read the results into an array and then use the php usort function to sort them into the desired order (but then to be useful you need to store the details between page refreshes), or you can sort in javascript on the client machine (but then you need to download all the data to the client which rather wrecks any speed gains from paging)

And example of doing this within php (not tested so excuse any typos):-

```
<?php

switch (true)
{
    case is_array($_SESSION['details']) AND $_POST['sort_order'] == 'id' :
        $Details = $_SESSION['details'];
        usort($Details, 'id_sort');
        break;
    case is_array($_SESSION['details']) AND $_POST['sort_order'] == 'name' :
        $Details = $_SESSION['details'];
        usort($Details, 'name_sort');
        break;
    case is_array($_SESSION['details']) AND $_POST['sort_order'] == 'dob' :
        $Details = $_SESSION['details'];
        usort($Details, 'dob_sort');
        break;
    case is_array($_SESSION['details']) AND $_POST['sort_order'] == 'home_town' :
        $Details = $_SESSION['details'];
        usort($Details, 'home_town_sort');
        break;
    default :
        $sql = "SELECT id, name, dob, home_town FROM Persons";

        $Query = $db->query($sql);

        $Details = array();

        while($row=$db->fetchAssoc($Query)) 
        {
            $Details[] = $row;
        }
        $_SESSION['details'] = $Details;
        break;
}

foreach($Details AS $aDetail)
{
    echo $aDetail['id']."\t".$aDetail['name']."\t".$aDetail['dob']."\t".$aDetail['home_town']."\r\n";
}

function id_sort($a,$b)
{
    $RetVar = 0;
    switch (true)
    {
        case $a['id'] > $b['id'] :
            $RetVar = 1;
            break;
        case $a['id'] < $b['id'] :
            $RetVar = -1;
            break;
        default :
            $RetVar = 0;
            break;
    }
    return $RetVar;
}

function name_sort($a,$b)
{
    $RetVar = 0;
    switch (true)
    {
        case $a['name'] > $b['name'] :
            $RetVar = 1;
            break;
        case $a['name'] < $b['name'] :
            $RetVar = -1;
            break;
        default :
            switch (true)
            {
                case $a['id'] > $b['id'] :
                    $RetVar = 1;
                    break;
                case $a['id'] < $b['id'] :
                    $RetVar = -1;
                    break;
                default :
                    $RetVar = 0;
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
    return $RetVar;
}

function dob_sort($a,$b)
{
    $RetVar = 0;
    switch (true)
    {
        case $a['dob'] > $b['dob'] :
            $RetVar = 1;
            break;
        case $a['dob'] < $b['dob'] :
            $RetVar = -1;
            break;
        default :
            switch (true)
            {
                case $a['name'] > $b['name'] :
                    $RetVar = 1;
                    break;
                case $a['name'] < $b['name'] :
                    $RetVar = -1;
                    break;
                default :
                    switch (true)
                    {
                        case $a['id'] > $b['id'] :
                            $RetVar = 1;
                            break;
                        case $a['id'] < $b['id'] :
                            $RetVar = -1;
                            break;
                        default :
                            $RetVar = 0;
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
    return $RetVar;
}

function home_town_sort($a,$b)
{
    $RetVar = 0;
    switch (true)
    {
        case $a['home_town'] > $b['home_town'] :
            $RetVar = 1;
            break;
        case $a['home_town'] < $b['home_town'] :
            $RetVar = -1;
            break;
        default :
            switch (true)
            {
                case $a['name'] > $b['name'] :
                    $RetVar = 1;
                    break;
                case $a['name'] < $b['name'] :
                    $RetVar = -1;
                    break;
                default :
                    switch (true)
                    {
                        case $a['id'] > $b['id'] :
                            $RetVar = 1;
                            break;
                        case $a['id'] < $b['id'] :
                            $RetVar = -1;
                            break;
                        default :
                            $RetVar = 0;
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
    }
    return $RetVar;
}

?>
```

Idea with this is that the details are stored (in the example I have used a session variable, but equally it could be a stored any other way you want), and if the details are found and a sort order is passed then it uses usort to sort that array of details. One function is used for each sort order, hence you can also change the sub orders (ie, id should be unique so you can sort based on that, but home town in this example would probably not be unique hence sort on name within that, and then id within that).

You don't have to specify the sorts down to that level, but I thought it worthwhile for this example.

Comment: There's no jquery, it's PHP.  I know how to use ORDER BY in a simple query, but I'm trying to use it AFTER an initial query.  How do I add the ORDER BY clause to query that's already been completed?

Comment: You can' add it to the query like that. You either need to redo the query with a different order by clause, or sort the result set that you have already retrieved (either on the server side in php or on the client side in javascript).

Comment: Can you provide an easy example of how to use PHP to sort the result set that I've retrieved? I just looked at the documentation for usort and got a headache from it!